# Chess Construction Challenge #5: Can't pass-ant up the chance!

Tags: chess, construction

For the end of the year, here is a random challenge to boggle your brains!

Given that:

> White has their king, a queen, two rooks, a knight, and seven pawns

> Black has their king and seven pawns

Construct:

> A legal position in which White forces Black to capture en passant 7 times, as in it's Black's only legal move, in at most 13 moves, if not fewer.

Have fun solving! I already have such a position, it is not impossible! You get bonus points for a sequence in less than 13 moves or proving that at least 13 moves are needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this does it:

> [FEN "7Q/8/3R1R2/K5k1/ppppppp1/N7/1PPPPPPP/8 w - - 0 1"]
>  [image]
>  1.h4+ gxh3 2.Rg6+ Kf5 3.g4+ fxg3 4.Qf8+ Ke5 5.f4+ exf3 6.Rde6+ Kd5 7.e4+
>  dxe3 8.Qd8+ Kc5 9.d4+ cxd3 10.Qb6+ Kd5 11.c4+ bxc3 12.Qd8+ Kc5 13.b4+ axb3

[Replay](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/a/922/24424)

Comment: Perfect solution! This is *exactly* what I had, just the other way around.

Comment: Great job on the king juggling!

Comment: @Bass thx, nice edit, too. What's that resource?

Comment: Screenshot of chess.com analysis board.

Comment: @Bass like the set, reminds me of crazy Russian chess books.

Comment: @RewanDemontay with the benefit of hindsight the construction seems perfectly straightforward, I wonder why it was so difficult to find, Anyway, interesting puzzle as always.